# No GRUB menu Lubuntu 12.04 PowerPC, only text

Tags: boot, grub2, lubuntu

I installed Lubuntu 12.04 on my iBook G4 over OS X 10.4.11. I had to manually add the b43 internet driver, but that and the rest of the installation went fine. I'm now updating.

However, when I rebooted, I got a strange boot screen. Obviously the mac bootloader had been overwritten, but GRUB, AFAIK, hadn't been installed! It gave me a command-line-like screen that says:

```
First Stage Ubuntu Boot
enter L for Linux, c for CD
boot:
```

which, when I push <kbd>L</kbd> and <kbd>enter</kbd>, takes me to the yaboot screen:

```
Welcome to yaboot 1.3.6
```

from which Lubuntu is loaded.

My question is, why isn't GRUB installed and how can I install it?

**EDIT**: I updated what the bootloader says. See above

**EDIT**: I have been borking around the internet trying to solve this myself and have found a [viable solution](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCFAQ#Can_I_install_grub2.3F), except it hasn't done anything.